# Pointer to pointer in c source file

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, pointer-to-pointer

I see a code which says the following.

```
typedef struct dummy
{
    int a;
    int b[100];
} dummy_t;

typedef struct dummya
{
    int a;
    int b;
} dummya_t;


void * getptr(){
    // return a pointer of a memory
}

void function(){
    dummya_t*dstptr = getptr();
    dummy_t *srcpt = (dummy_t*)(dstptr->b);
}
```

I can see dummy_t `*srcpt = (dummy_t*)(dstptr->b);` meaning as a pointer is pointing to another pointer but then `*srcpt` should be a double pointer right? Like `**srcpt`

Comment: The presented code does not make a sense.

Comment: `dummy_t *srcpt = XXX` is not dereferencing `*srcpt`. It's declaring `srcpt` as a pointer, and initializing with the value of `XXX`.

Comment: but XXX is a pointer. So how does it correlate ?

Comment: "meaning as a pointer is pointing to another pointer " No.  It's more like `int x = dstptr->b;  dummy_t *srcpt = x`  A value is being assigned to `srcpt`.  The cast is there to poke holes in the type system not allow the compiler to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: But in the current code that I'm working on which builds fine. 
it says dummy_t *srcpt = (dummy_t*)(dstptr->b); and it builds fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct, you can not cast nor assign using pointers to objects of different types, for example:

```
struct a { int a, b; };
struct b { int a, b; };
```

are different objects even having the same members.

```
struct a x = {.a = 1, .b = 2};
struct b *y = &x; // wrong
```

> I can see dummy_t *srcpt = (dummy_t*)(dstptr->b); meaning as a pointer
> is pointing to another pointer but then *srcpt should be a double
> pointer right? Like **srcpt

Your assumptions are not correct, a basic example using plain pointers to `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2};
    int *a = &arr[0];
    int *b = &arr[1];

    printf("a = %d b = %d\n", *a, *b);

    int **ptr;

    ptr = &a;
    *ptr = &arr[1];
    ptr = &b;
    *ptr = &arr[0];

    printf("a = %d b = %d\n", *a, *b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
a = 1 b = 2
a = 2 b = 1
```

As you can see, you use a double pointer (`**ptr`) when you want to change the contents of `a` or `b` (the address where it points to), a more useful example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int **a, int **b)
{
    int *temp = *a;

    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2};
    int *a = &arr[0];
    int *b = &arr[1];

    printf("a = %d b = %d\n", *a, *b);

    swap(&a, &b);

    printf("a = %d b = %d\n", *a, *b);

    return 0;
}
```

Same output:

```
a = 1 b = 2
a = 2 b = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can see `dummy_t *srcpt = (dummy_t*)(dstptr->b);` meaning as a pointer is pointing to another pointer but then `*srcpt` should be a double pointer right? Like `**srcpt`

No.  That line means "treat the value of `dstptr->b` *as though* it were a value of type `dummy_t *`, and assign it to `srcpt`".  It's not a pointer to a pointer.

The expression `dstptr->b` has type `int`, which cannot be directly assigned to a pointer type.  `(dummy_t *)` is a *cast*, which tells the compiler to convert the type.

Like Vlad says in his comment, this code doesn't make any sense.  It may compile, but just because it compiles doesn't mean it's right.